# Try to use "Enter" key to submit form

Tags: qooxdoo

I ask your help Everybody. :-)

Here is [a link](http://preview.tinyurl.com/ychzpnxw) to Playground.

The problem you can see if to look at the console or debug log.

If you fill the text fields and press "Enter" key, you can see that only the first field can get the value. Second one is NULL.
If you tap "Enter" key second time - there is no problem at all.
But if you clean fields and fill it up again - the same problem will be back.

If I use just a button with "execute" event - there is no problem.

Is it a bug or something wrong about my code?

Comment: IE11 works ok, but Firefox (win7,version 54.0.1, x32) shows me an error: _GlobalError: this.getContentElement(...) is null_. So, it is bug

Comment: Chrome(win7 59.0.3071.115, x64) works ok too

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that the changed value of the textfield is applied to the model only when the [textfield looses focus](http://www.qooxdoo.org/devel/api/#qx.ui.form.AbstractField~changeValue) (or after you pressed `Enter`). So yo have to set the `liveUpdate` property to `true`. [Here](http://www.qooxdoo.org/5.0.2/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22qx.Class.define(%2522demobrowser.demo.data.FormController%2522%252C%250D%250A%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520extend%2520%253A%2520qx.application.Standalone%252C%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520members%2520%253A%250D%250A%2520%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520main%253A%2520function()%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.base(arguments)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520container%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.container.Composite(new%2520qx.ui.layout.Canvas())%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.getRoot().add(container)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520form%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Form()%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520userEmail%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.TextField().set(%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520required%253A%2520true%252C%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520width%253A200%252C%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520placeholder%253A%2520%2522user%2540email.com%2522%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520form.add(userEmail%252C%2520%2522User%2520Email%2522%252C%2520null%252C%2520%2522email%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520userPhone%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.TextField().set(%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520required%253A%2520true%252C%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520placeholder%253A%2520%252200123456789%2522%252C%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520liveUpdate%2520%253A%2520true%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520form.add(userPhone%252C%2520%2522Phone%2520number%2522%252C%2520null%252C%2520%2522phone%2522)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520controller%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.data.controller.Form(null%252C%2520form)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520model%2520%253D%2520controller.createModel()%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520renderer%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.renderer.Single(form).set(%257Bpadding%253A50%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520container.add(renderer)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.getRoot().addListener(%2522keypress%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520key%2520%253D%2520e.getKeyIdentifier().toLowerCase()%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520switch(key)%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520case%2520%2522enter%2522%253A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(form.validate())%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520console.log(model)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520email%2520%253D%2520model.getEmail()%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520phone%2520%253D%2520model.getPhone()%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520console.log(email)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520console.log(phone)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.debug(email)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.debug(phone)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%2509%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%252C%2520this)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250D%250A%2520%2520%257D%250D%250A%257D)%253B%250D%250A%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D) is your playground example updated.

```js
var userPhone = new qx.ui.form.TextField().set({
  required: true,
  placeholder: "00123456789",
  liveUpdate : true
});
```

Comment: You are the best! Thank you. :-)

Comment: And I have other solution as well. 

selfUpdate param is false by default, you should use true instead
var controller = new qx.data.controller.Form(null, this.form, true);
var model = controller.createModel();

 and before get the model, just: controller.updateModel();

Works fine.